# MongoDB - How do I restore a binary backup file?

Tags: mongodb

I have a database backup and I don't know how to restore it into MongoDB.
I'm also not sure exactly what command caused this backup as I changed the OS along with the script that handled this.
I believe it was either `mongoexport` or `mongodump`.

It shows as a 'data' file:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/db-backup $ file 2021-05-04 
2021-05-04: data
```

It has binary ('octet stream') data in this format:

```
@everyoneposition__v�_id177130053690273793colo#ffffffpermissions��guildId17713005369027379mentionablhoistedname
@everyoneposition__v�_id177131002513145857colo#ffffffpermissions��guildId17713100251314585mentionablhoistedname
```

How do I restore this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongoexport tool writes out JSON or CSV files, that snippet is neither, so probably rules that out.

Mongodump can write to a single archive, a directory structure containing BSON and JSON files, or a single BSON file, all with or without gzip.

The file utility should recognize gzip data as such, and an uncompressed mongodump archive might be recognized as either `data` or an unusual type like `DIY-Thermocam raw data`.

A BSON file is also recognized by file as `data`.

To test which this is, execute

```
bsondump 2021-05-04
```

If it fails on the first document with `invalid BSONSize:` showing an enormous or negative value, it is most likely a mongodump archive that you can try to restore with

```
mongorestore --archive=2021-05-04
```

If it lists out a series of documents, it is a BSON file that you could restore with

```
mongorestore --db=databasename --collection=collname 2021-05-04
```

Comment: Worth to mention that Mongo restore has an option `--dryRun` you may use.